# MongoDb Mass Saving "isOK() checkWriteError" Exception

Tags: java, mongodb, exception, save

I'm trying to write a parser and and I'm using MongoDB as a database. Essentially it is going through, creating objects, and then saving them. It is doing this several times a second. After around 164 objects are saved it crashes with this error:

> com.mongodb.MongoException: isOk() at
>   com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._checkWriteError(DBTCPConnector.java:130)
>   at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:142) at
>   com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:141) at
>   com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:97) at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:61) at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:547) at
>   com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:638) at
>   com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:685) at
>   com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:679) at
>   com.soleo.internal.releasenotes.orm.Storage.save(Storage.java:764) at
>   com.soleo.internal.releasenotes.page.MainPage$2.onSubmit(MainPage.java:256)

Now at one point I had over 1000 objects in this same database, I just didn't insert them all at once. So it can't be a hard drive space issue. I can't find any documentation at all of this error online. Oddly it's only when I try saving THIS object. If I try saving Object B after the crash it saves just fine. It just crashes on Object A, the one I initially mass saved.

I ran a test multiple times and it failed in the same place. I used random values so I could prove it wasn't a variable issue:

```
FIRST TRY:
==============================
CREATING RELEASE #162
Component: iHateYou
Location: 250344
Version: 8.8.1.5-2
Date: Sun Feb 07 00:00:00 EST 3188 (02-07-3188)
SAVING.............
SUCCESS.
==============================
CREATING RELEASE #163
Component: iHateYou
Location: 227407
Version: 5.5.7.6-7
Date: Sat Mar 04 00:00:00 EST 439 (03-04-439)
SAVING.............
SUCCESS.
==============================
CREATING RELEASE #164
Component: iHateYou
Location: 38694
Version: 3.5.4.7-7
Date: Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 EST 158 (01-03-158)
SAVING.............
Oct 28, 2011 11:17:11 AM org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle logRuntimeException
SEVERE: isOk()
com.mongodb.MongoException: isOk()
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._checkWriteError(DBTCPConnector.java:130)
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:142)


SECOND TRY:
==============================
CREATING RELEASE #162
Component: iHateYou
Location: 64717
Version: 0.1.0.4-8
Date: Sun May 07 00:00:00 EST 971 (05-07-971)
SAVING.............
SUCCESS.
==============================
CREATING RELEASE #163
Component: iHateYou
Location: 19360
Version: 4.5.8.1-3
Date: Wed Aug 04 00:00:00 EST 1339 (08-04-1339)
SAVING.............
SUCCESS.
==============================
CREATING RELEASE #164
Component: iHateYou
Location: 115518
Version: 0.0.8.0-2
Date: Sat Apr 07 00:00:00 EST 143 (04-07-143)
SAVING.............
Oct 28, 2011 11:15:28 AM org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle logRuntimeException
SEVERE: isOk()
com.mongodb.MongoException: isOk()
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._checkWriteError(DBTCPConnector.java:130)
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:142)
```

Here's some partially obfuscated code:

```
Random blank = new Random();
ObjectRef blah = new ObjectRef("iHateYou");
storage.save(blah);

for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
{
    System.out.println("==============================\nCREATING OBJECT #" + i);
    ObjectA saveMe = new ObjectA();
    saveMe.setRef(storage.getRefByName("iHateYou"));
    System.out.println("Component: " + saveMe.getRef.getName());
    saveMe.setLocation(blank.nextInt(300000) + "");
    System.out.println("Location: " + saveMe.getLocation());
    saveMe.setVersion(new Version(blank.nextInt(9) + "." + blank.nextInt(9) + "." + blank.nextInt(9) + "." + blank.nextInt(9) + "-" + blank.nextInt(9)));
    System.out.println("Version: " + saveMe.getVersion());

    try 
    {
        String randomDate = "0" + blank.nextInt(9) + "-0" + blank.nextInt(9) + "-" + blank.nextInt(4000);
        saveMe.setReleaseDate(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").parse(randomDate));
        System.out.println("Date: " + saveMe.getReleaseDate() + " (" + randomDate + ") ");
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    System.out.println("SAVING.............");
    storage.save(saveMe);
    System.out.println("SUCCESS.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a variation of this bug: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-324

Are you using sharding? In that case your config DB might be corrupt. The driver is probably not expecting to receive the message "isOk" back.

Please tell us more about your environment: MongoDB version, using sharding or not, driver version, etc.